# saving values passed throught array and without array using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, phpmyadmin

*I am passing a set of values as array from a page using ajax.And i saved those values to a table created in phpmyadmin.

*Now what i want is that i am also passing some other values which are not in this array.And i am getting it here in this back page code written below.

*Here i want to save emp_id ,and then the array values to the same row where the emp_id is just stored.

I cannot do it..i tries in many ways...can you please help me.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['var1']))
{
    $emp_id =$_REQUEST['var1'];//i got this value
    $sql11="insert into timesheet_entry(emp_id) values ('$emp_id')";
    mysql_query($sql11);


}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------



if(isset($_REQUEST['arr']))
{

    //here i am trying to get the id of the last row and then update the row with ref to this id

    $sql_id="select id from timesheet_entry where emp_id='$emp_id'";
    $res_id=mysql_query($sql_id);
    while($rowid=mysql_fetch_array($res_id))
    {
        $id1=$rowid['id'];
    }




    $all_data=array();
    $all_data=array_chunk($_REQUEST['arr'], 19);
    foreach($all_data as $values)
    {   


        $sql="update  timesheet_entry set(s_st='$values[0]',s_ot='$values[1]',m_st='$values[2]',m_ot='$values[3]',t_st='$values[4]',t_ot='$values[5]',w_st='$values[6]',w_ot='$values[7]',th_st='$values[8]',th_ot='$values[9]',f_st='$values[10]',f_ot='$values[11]',sa_st='$values[12]',sa_ot='$values[13]',job_code='$values[14]',job_name='$values[15]',st_tot='$values[16]',ot_tot=,'$values[17]',pm='$values[18]') where id=$id1";






            if(mysql_query($sql))
            {

                echo "success";

            }
            else
            {
                echo "fail";
            } 



    } 
}
```

Comment: for now, variables inside single quotes must not work. eg. '$emp_id'

Comment: @sinazza :i am able to dispaly the value of $id1 though